# Finding the average value of a cubic function

Tags: calculus

> Let $p(x)=ax^{3}+bx^{2}+cx+d$. There exists real numbers $r$ and $s$(independent of $a,b,c$ and $d$) $0<r<s<1$. For which the average value of $p(x)$ on the interval $[0,1]$ is equal to the average value of $p(r)$ and $p(s)$. Find the product of $rs$ expressed as a fraction.

What I know is $$f_{\text{avg}}=\frac{1}{b-a}\int\limits_a^bf(x)dx$$

$$f_{\text{avg}}=\int\limits_0^1f(x)dx$$

From that I am having trouble finding $r$ or $s$. I would think they would be the same but they clearly can't be. I know how to plug in the right values and take the integral but after that unsure. I'm having trouble understanding the question or what to try. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your expression for the average value is wrong.

Comment: I took the formula from wikipedia for the mean of a function over an interval. Or did I read the question wrong?

Comment: @HighSchool15: in the average formula, you've replaced the limits of integration with the appropriate 0 and 1 for this problem, but you did not do so for the denominator, which in this case also has $b = 1$ and $a = 0$. This is particularly confusing since $a$ and $b$ have a different meaning in the problem (where they are coefficients of the polynomial, not limits of integration).

Comment: @HighSchool15 To be more specific, what are $a$ and $b$ in your formula for $f_{avg}$?

Comment: Try to compute the average (the integral). Try writing down $p(r)$ and $p(s)$ in terms of $a,b,c,d$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question probably misses a condition $a,b,c,d\ne0$.
We have
\begin{align}
p_{\mathrm{avg}} &= \tfrac14 a+\tfrac13 b+\tfrac12 c+d
=p(r)+p(s)
=
\tfrac12 (r^3+s^3)a
+
\tfrac12 (r^2+s^2)b
+
\tfrac12(r+s)c
+d
\end{align}

From this system we have
\begin{align}
\tfrac12 r+\tfrac12s &=\tfrac12
\\
\tfrac12 s^2+\tfrac12 r^2&=\tfrac13
\end{align}

Which gives $rs=\tfrac16$.

Moreover, we can find that 
$r=\tfrac12-\tfrac16\sqrt{3}$,
$s=\tfrac12+\tfrac16\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: Oh wow I miss read average of $p(r)+p(s)$ as the average value of each separately. Thank you very clear now.